# Dividing datasets into fully-correlating subsets

Tags: regression, correlation, graph-theory, subset

I have a dataset of $N$ variables of which I know that (at least) one combination of their disjoint subsets results in non-negative correlation coefficients for all variables in these subsets. The subsets might have a different number of elements.

For example: The variables $A,B,C,D,E,F$ have the following correlation coefficient matrix (only showing the upper triangle)

```
    A     B     C     D     E     F   
A   1     0.32  0.3   0.04 -0.03 -0.02
B   0     1     0.3   0.08 -0.03  0.01
C   0     0     1     0.01  0.02  0.02
D   0     0     0     1     0.28  0.3 
E   0     0     0     0     1     0.3 
F   0     0     0     0     0     1
```

In this case, a complete description of this data in positive-only correlations would be $\{A,B,C\}$ and $\{D,E,F\}$ (The sub-matrices of these two sets only contain positive correlation coefficients). Another possible combination is $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and $\{E,F\}$ (as is $\{A,B\}, \{C,D\}, \{E,F\}$).

In the example above, $\{A,B,C\}$ and $\{D,E,F\}$ was indeed the looked-for combination, but I cannot find a way to favor this possibility of decomposition without prior knowledge. Since $D$ has a correlation coefficient close to $0$ (and has a higher absolute value with $\{A,B\}$ than with $\{E,F\}$), I don't see using the absolute value of the correlation coefficients as the way to go.

As said, I know that there are such relations in my data, so I'm not trying to find something in the data [that isn't there](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32254/236460), I'm just trying to retrieve the inherent structure of the data.

Is there a clever way to find such a combination of subsets? If so, is there a generalization if such a decomposition of the data set exists, but does not use all $N$ variables (let's say in the example above, another variabe $G$ would be added which is just noise and thus might -- by chance -- be anti-correlating to any other number of variables)?

I have been looking into ways to do this by constructing a graph where the variables are the nodes and the edges describe only positive correlations. The cliques in this graph then represent all possible decompositions, but not only a complete one.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this problem fits into the scope of community detection in networks, which is difficult to generalize and rather ill-defined.  However, there has been some progress focusing on the structure of correlation matrices: [Community Detection for Correlation Matrices](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.5.021006).  Unfortunately, very few methods will give you structure over only a subset of the graph, and I don't know any such methods designed for correlation matrices.  Perhaps an extension of [link communities](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature09182) or [OSLOM](http://www.oslom.org) would be able to determine those subsets that are statistical significant.